# Aligning target names with configuration in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, configuration, static-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I'm taking a 32-bit source library and compiling on a 64-bit platform and getting alignment issues (not only 32-bit vs 64-bit but also character set as well).

I want to place all the 64 bit configurations into a "Win64" folder and the 32-bit configurations into a "Win32" directory.

I'm looking into some guidance for modifying the project file so that the target library and dll filenames will be in terms of the configuration.

Examples:

- Win64/testrunner_x64d.lib -- Library, debug, 64-bit platform, ASCII
  character set.
- Win64/testrunner_x64ud.lib -- Library, debug, 64-bit platform,
  Unicode character set.
- Win32/testrunner_x32d.lib -- Library, debug, 32-bit platform, ASCII
  character set.
- Win32/testrunner_x32ud.lib -- Library, debug, 32-bit platform,
  Unicode character set.

I'm new to using configurations in Visual Studio 2010 and also porting an existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the character setting,  go to "Configuration Properties"->"General"->"Project Defaults"->"Character Set", chose the one as you wish.

For the lib's name for different configuration, you can set it via "Linker"->"General"->"Output File"